# implementing simple pagination on mustache php?

Tags: php, pagination, mustache

hi i just starting to use mustache for php, i need include a simple paginator from my data
i just try this form but doesn't work

```
echo $m->render('<head><title></title></head><body>'.include('blogs/load_data.php').'

    </body></html>' , $data);
```

where load_data.php contain my paginator code, i just make a deep search on google and don`t find a example how i can achieve this. any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish here. What exactly is in `blogs/load_data.php`?